# Identifying a Number Theoretic Function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Does the arithmetic function $\xi_{s}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$
$$\xi_s(n)=\sum_{p\mid n}p^{-s}$$
exist in literature? If it makes any difference I only care about square-free inputs $n$ so it may be that it simplifies to an existing function in that case, if it isn't already one. In this special case of $n$ square-free I managed to derive
$$\xi_s(n)=\sigma_{-s}(n)(\omega(n)-1)^{-1}\left(\left[\sum_{p\mid n}\sum_{q\mid n}\frac{q^s}{p^s(q^s+1)}\right]-1\right)$$
but I wouldn't call this an improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approximation $\xi_1(n)\sim\log\log\log n$ is quite famous but $\xi_s$ is not a multiplicative function.
We have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\xi_s(n)}{n^t}=\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}\sum_{n:p\mid n}\frac{1}{n^t}=\sum_p\frac{\zeta(t)}{p^{s+t}}\tag{1}$$
and in terms of the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function)
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\xi_s(n)}{n^t} = \zeta(t)\,P(s+t)=\zeta(t)\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log\zeta(ms+mt).\tag{2} $$

Comment: Thanks. It in fact arose while messing around with the zeta and prime zeta function.

Comment: Does the related sum, $\sum_{n\ge 1}\mu(n)\xi_s(n)/n^t$, also have a representation with prime zeta and zeta functions? If not then what about when $t=s$?

Comment: @WillFisher: performing formal manipulations we should have $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)\xi_s(n)}{n^t}=\sum_p \frac{1}{p^{s+t}}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(pm)}{m^t}$$

Comment: That can be written as $$-\sum_p \frac{1}{p^{s}(p^t-1)\zeta(t)} $$

Comment: You are free to take $t=s$ both in the original pseudo-Dirichlet series and in the twisted (through $\mu(n)$) pseudo-Dirichlet series.